# Java mail client not downloading attachments for icloud messages

Tags: java, email

I have a java mail client (1.3 or 1.4) that works fine for messages sent from gmail and many other different accounts. However if the messages is sent from icloud.com account then the attachments can not be downloaded. The following is complete working example

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

/**
* This program demonstrates how to download e-mail messages and save
* attachments into files on disk.
*
*
*/
public class EmailAttachmentReceiver {
private String saveDirectory;

/**
 * Sets the directory where attached files will be stored.
 * @param dir absolute path of the directory
 */
public void setSaveDirectory(String dir) {
    this.saveDirectory = dir;
}

/**
 * Downloads new messages and saves attachments to disk if any.
 * @param host
 * @param port
 * @param userName
 * @param password
 */
public void downloadEmailAttachments(String host, String port,
        String userName, String password) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    // server setting
    properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);

    // SSL setting
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",
            String.valueOf(port));

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    try {
        // connects to the message store
        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(userName, password);

        // opens the inbox folder
        Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        // fetches new messages from server
        Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
            Message message = arrayMessages[i];
            Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
            String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
            String subject = message.getSubject();
            String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

            String contentType = message.getContentType();
            String messageContent = "";

            // store attachment file name, separated by comma
            String attachFiles = "";

            if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                // content may contain attachments
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                System.out.println("Content type is multipart. contentType=" + contentType + " numberOfParts=" + numberOfParts);                    
                for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                    System.out.println("part.getDisposition()=" + part.getDisposition() + " part.getFileName()=" +  part.getFileName());
                    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                        // this part is attachment
                        String fileName = part.getFileName();
                        System.out.println("This part is attachment. fileName=" + fileName);                            
                        attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                        part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This part may be the message content");                         
                        // this part may be the message content
                        messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                    }
                }//for end

                if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                    attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                }
            } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                    || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                Object content = message.getContent();
                if (content != null) {
                    messageContent = content.toString();
                }
            }

            // print out details of each message
            System.out.println("Message #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
            System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
            System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
            System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
            System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
        }

        // disconnect
        folderInbox.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Runs this program with Gmail POP3 server
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "pop.gmail.com";
    String port = "995";
    String userName = "complete email address";
    String password = "password";

    String saveDirectory = "C:/Attachment";

    EmailAttachmentReceiver receiver = new EmailAttachmentReceiver();
    receiver.setSaveDirectory(saveDirectory);
    receiver.downloadEmailAttachments(host, port, userName, password);

 }
}
```

The following code line makes a check for the attachment
`if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition()))`
In case of an icloud message the `part.getDisposition()` returns null. I also tried to save each part to the file but they do not happen to be the attachments that the email has.